# Drive boots in desktop, not in laptop, can not find OS

Tags: windows-10, boot

We have a laptop that quit working.
We removed the internal SSD and placed it in a desktop and it booted cleanly to Windows 10.
We placed it into 3 different laptop models, and it would not boot.
The BIOS reports that it can not find an OS.
Placed back into another desktop, it boots perfectly.

Let me clarify here... **the OS does not fail**.
The OS never gets a chance to start.  The BIOS reports that no OS is found.  Something in the MBR?  Or an issue with UEFI vs legacy?  Or ...?

We tried making a clone onto a mechanical hard drive, and it behaves the same way.
We tried turning on Legacy Support in the BIOS on one laptop, and it made no change.

We tried a program to restore the MBR on the clone, and it didn't help.

At this point we have no idea what else to try.  We have read up on the boot process, and are overwhelmed (we don't understand it... it seems overly complicated).

The attached images show what Aomei's partition assistant knows about the partitions.

Any help would be appreciated.  We want the disk to run again in a Laptop.
[image: screen shot 1]
[image: screen shot 2]

(My friend and I volunteer with our retirement community to help people with their computer problems.  The original laptop belongs to a resident.  The computers we have tried it in are ones that have been donated to the community's associated non-profit organization for refurbishment and resale.)

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Was the OS on this drive originally installed in the laptop or was it initially cloned from desktop drive?  A laptop drive will not normally boot perfectly in a desktop (BIOS and drivers).

Comment: The OS was installed on the original laptop and was functioning well.  The laptop's connector appears to have jostled loose from the hard drive, so it obviously quit working.  It no longer works in that laptop as there is a BIOS issue now and nothing displays on the screen.  But the drive DOES work when plugged into a desktop.

Comment: I have not seen a laptop drive boot properly in a desktop computer. I find that strange.

Comment: We have found Windows 10 to be amazingly forgiving.  We have moved another Win10 hard drive from another laptop to a desktop with no problems.  We've also had few problems moving between different makes of desktops.  However, one move between desktops resulted in a similar situation where the OS could not be found.  We tried adding a dual boot with Linux Mint 20, and it recognized Windows was installed, but when done still wouldn't boot Windows.

Comment: At the installation stage, Windows is tailored to the hardware it finds, and in the case of an OEM version, the activation is tied to the hardware (chipset, hdd, cpu etc). Even with an identical model you would expect activation issues if not others because of e.g. CPU stepping, chipset revision, BIOS version etc. With non-identical hardware all bets are off and you may or not be lucky. Essentially, OS transfer by HDD transplant is not supported.

Comment: I could accept the OS failing... but the OS is NOT FOUND.  It doesn't even get a chance to start.  There is something in the boot sequence which goes awry.

Comment: If Disk1 Basic GPT in the screenshot is the drive (HDD/SSD) in question, then it is GPT so Windows 10 is installed in UEFI mode. Is the BIOS of the laptop having option to manually boot from a file? If so what if you try to point it to \EFI\Boot\Bootx64.efi that resides on EFI partition? Does it boot?

Comment: I checked for an option to boot from a file, and unfortunately, could not find one.  Too bad, it sounded like such a good solution.
Is there some way to edit the UEFI boot procedure to use that same file?

Comment: Do you know how to boot into UEFI Shell? Download UEFI Shell from the following link.  https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/UDK2018/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell/X64/Shell.efi   Rename it as bootx64.efi. Create a FAT/FAT32 formatted pen drive. Create \EFI\Boot folders. Place this bootx64.efi at \EFI\Boot on pen drive. Set boot mode UEFI and disable secure boot in firmware. Now try booting thru this pen drive into UEFI Shell and see if you can run Bootx64.efi from the EFI Partition on the HDD/SSD where Windows is cloned/installed.

Comment: UEFI Shell.  Okay, I finally had time to try the UEFI Shell.  I was able to boot the pen drive and got a prompt.  But I could not find any documentation on what should be entered at the prompt... and nothing I tried seemed to be recognized.  Where can I find what commands are allowed / can you tell me what to type?